# getting error missing required keys: [:id] on a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am rendering a form in a view in the instance that an user has not verified their email.  This form also allows them to put in their email preferences.

Here is the form.

```
<%= form_tag update_email_and_sports_url, class: "form-signin", method: 'patch' do %>
  <h2>Please confirm your email</h2>
    <%= email_field_tag :email, nil, class: "input-block-level", placeholder: current_user.email %>
  <h2>We'll email you when opportunities arise to play any of the sports you select below:</h2>
    <%= check_box_tag :basketball, checked = false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :volleyball, checked = false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :soccer, checked = false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :football, checked = false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :hockey, checked = false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :kickball, checked = false %>
    <%= check_box_tag :softball, checked = false %>
    <%= f.hidden_field_tag :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<div>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", class:"btn btn-large btn-success" %>
</div>
```

The view will not even render and I'm getting this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update_preferences"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

It's saying the error is in my form_tag line.  Here is my route.

```
patch '/user/preferences/:id' => 'users#update_preferences', :as => 'update_email_and_sports'
```

And my controller

```
  def update_preferences
    current_user.email = params[:email]
    preference = Preference.new(preference_params)
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def preference_params
    params.require(:preference).permit(:user_id, :basketball, :football, :softball, :soccer, :kickball, :volleyball, :hockey)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't need id param to search for user in this action, you should remove it from your route to this action in routes.rb:

```
patch '/user/preferences' => 'users#update_preferences', :as => 'update_email_and_sports'
```

The error is raised because route with id included expects :id parameter, which you don't provide calling this route's helper.

Answer (score 2):

**Why is this happening?**

The `form_tag` path (or in your case, url) needs to take an `id` (or an object) of the `user` you want to update...  Something like:

`<%= form_tag update_email_and_sports_url(current_user), class: "form-signin", method: 'patch' do %>`

This will solve the error of `missing required keys: [:id]`.

**Potentially better idea...**

However, if you're using `current_user` always for this update, you may consider dropping `:id` from your route...  Then you'd leave the `form_tag` in your question as-is.